# pyspark error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am using pyspark 2.0 to create a DataFrame object by reading a csv using:

```
data = spark.read.csv('data.csv', header=True)
```

I find the type of the data using

```
type(data)
```

The result is

```
pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
```

I am trying to convert the some columns in data to LabeledPoint in order to apply a classification.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *    
from pyspark.sql.functions import loc
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

data.select(['label','features']).
              map(lambda row:LabeledPoint(row.label, row.features))
```

I came across with this problem:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Any idea on the error? Is there a way to generate a LabelPoint from DataFrame in order to perform classification?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535447/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-map)

Answer (score 20):

Use `.rdd.map`:

```
>>> data.select(...).rdd.map(...)
```

`DataFrame.map` has been removed in Spark 2.