# How to get rid of the row wrapper object in pyspark dataframes without using RDD api?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm issuing the following SQL statement against a tempview

```
cloudantdata.createOrReplaceTempView("washingflat")

sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT temperature FROM washingflat")
sqlDF.rdd.map(lambda row : row.temperature).collect()
```

I'm just interested in the plain (unwrapped) integer values. All I've tried so far with the dataframe API always returned Row-objects wrapping the values I'm interested in.

Is there a way to get the scalar contents without using the RDD api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given an input DataFrame

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': np.random.uniform(0,100, size = (100,)), 'City': 'LA'})
sqlContext.createDataFrame(test_df).registerTempTable('AgeTable')
```

There are two (primary) ways for extracting a value without using the Row abstraction. The first is to use the `.toPandas()` method of a DataFrame / SQL Query

```
print(sqlContext.sql("SELECT Age FROM AgeTable").toPandas()['Age'])
```

This returns a Pandas DataFrame / Series.

The second is to actually group the data inside of SQL and then extract it from a single `Row` object

```
al_qry = sqlContext.sql("SELECT City, COLLECT_SET(Age) as AgeList FROM AgeTable GROUP BY City")
al_qry.first()[0].AgeList
```

This returns a raw python list.

The more efficient way is with the `toPandas` method and this approach will likely be improved more in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You could manually put them in a list after collecting them as below

```
temps = []
rows = sqlDF.collect()
for r in rows:
    temps.append(r['temperature'])
```

Comment: I'm really missing the map function on dataframes

Comment: `map` function converted `DataFrame` to `RDD`. There is no difference between old `df.map(...)` and new `df.rdd.map(...)`. `collect` converts to `RDD` first too.

Comment: @RomeoKienzler Yea, Lost is correct. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535447/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-map/39536218#39536218

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>>
>>> chain.from_iterable(sqlDF.collect())
```

Comment: still uses rdd api :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't cut rdd part :)

Answer (score 0):

```
temp_list = [str(i.temperature) for i in sqlDF.select("temperatue").collect()]
```