# pyspark 2.2 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map' , backward compatibility is missing how to solve it

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I am working with Spark 1.6  below code is working fine:

```python
ddl = sqlContext.sql("""show create table {mytable }""".format(mytable="""mytest.my_dummytable"""))
map(''.join, ddl\
.map(lambda my_row: [str(data).replace("`", "'") for data in my_row])\
.collect())
```

However, when I moved to spark 2.2 I got the following exception:

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-> in <module>()
      1 ddl = sqlContext.sql("""show create table {mytable }""".format(mytable ="""mytest.my_dummytable"""))
----> 2 map(''.join, ddl..map(lambda my_row: [str(data).replace("`", "'") for data in my_row]).collect())

spark2/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in __getattr__(self, name)
            if name not in self.columns:
                raise AttributeError(
->                  "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
            jc = self._jdf.apply(name)
            return Column(jc)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `.rdd` first. Spark 2.0 stopped aliasing `df.map()` to `df.rdd.map()`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535447/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-map).

Comment: here we are missing backward compatibility please suggest me ..how to solve  the problem with out changing the existing  code

Comment: @DastagiriShaik You just have to call `.rdd` on your dataframe before calling `.map`.

Comment: @DastagiriShaik In your case, it’s `sqlContext.sql(“...”).rdd.map(...)`.

Comment: We deployed  the project with pyspark 1.6  already.. when i  want to migrate to 2.2 .. i am getting problem..is there any way to work  ...with out changing existing code...

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I don’t believe that’s possible unfortunately.