# pandas 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have two df - df_a and df_b,

```
# df_a
number    cur    code
1000      USD    700
2000      USD    800
3000      USD    900

# df_b
number    amount    deletion code
1000      0.0       L        700
1000      10.0      X        700
1000      10.0      X        700
2000      20.0      X        800
2000      20.0      X        800
3000      0.0       L        900
3000      0.0       L        900
```

I want to left merge `df_a` with `df_b`,

```
df_a = df_a.merge(df_b.loc[df_b.deletion != 'L'], how='left', on=['number', 'code'])
```

and also, create a flag called `deleted` in the merge result `df_a`, that has three possible values - full, partial and none;

`full` - if all rows associated with a particular `number` value, have `deletion` = L;

`partial` - if some rows associated with a particular `number` value, have `deletion` = L;

`none` - no rows associated with a particular `number` value, have `deletion` = L;

Also when doing the merge, rows from `df_b` with `deletion` = L should not be considered; so the result looks like,

```
 number    amount    deletion    deleted    cur    code
 1000      10.0      X           partial    USD    700
 1000      10.0      X           partial    USD    700
 2000      20.0      X           none       USD    800
 2000      20.0      X           none       USD    800
 3000      0.0       NaN         full       USD    900
```

I tried,

```
g = df_b['deletion'].ne('L').groupby([df_b['number'], df_b['code']])
m1 = g.any()
m2 = g.all()

d1 = dict.fromkeys(m1.index[m1 & ~m2], 'partial')
d2 = dict.fromkeys(m2.index[m2], 'full')

d = {**d1, **d2}
df_a = df_a.merge(df_b.loc[df_b.deletion != 'L'], how='left', on=['code', 'number'])

df_a['deleted'] = df_a[['number', 'code']].map(d).fillna('none')
```

but I got an error,

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

It seems `df` does not have `map` function, so I am wondering if there are any alternative ways to achieve this.

Comment: @jpp sry, updated again, i was trying to `df_a['deleted'] = df_a[['number', 'code']].map(d).fillna('none')`, which caused the error, so wondering if there is any other way to do the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535447/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-map)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame` objects don't have a `map` method. You can instead construct an index from two columns and use `pd.Index.map` with a function:

```
df_a['deleted'] = df_a.set_index(['number', 'code']).index.map(d.get)
df_a['deleted'] = df_a['deleted'].fillna('none')
```

#### Compatibility note

For Pandas versions >0.25, you can use `pd.Index.map` directly with a dictionary, i.e. use `d` instead of `d.get`.

For prior versions, we use `d.get` instead of `d` because, unlike `pd.Series.map`, `pd.Index.map` does not accept a dictionary directly. But it can accept a function such as `dict.get`. Note also we split apart the `fillna` operation as `pd.Index.map` returns an array rather than a series.