# Multiply pandas dataframe by vlookup

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataframe with multiple years of sales data and tens of thousands of skew_ids (i.e.):

```
     date      skew_id  units_sold
0 2001-01-01      123       1
1 2001-01-02      123       2
2 2001-01-03      123       3
3 2001-01-01      456       4
4 2001-01-02      456       5
...
```

I have another dataframe that maps skew_ids to skew_price (i.e.):

```
  skew_id  skew_price
0   123       100.00
1   456       10.00
...
```

My first dataframe is so large that I cannot merge without hitting my memory limit.

I'd like to calculate the daily revenues (i.e.):

```
    date       revenue
0 2001-01-01      140      
1 2001-01-02      250       
2 2001-01-03      300       
...
```

Comment: I suggest you split the large `df` to smaller pieces, and merge them one by one (in a loop, of course).

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Edited to include expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends of number of rows, number of unique `skew_id` values and size of `RAM`.

One possible solution with `map`:

```
df1['revenue'] = df1['skew_id'].map(df2.set_index('skew_id')['skew_price']) * df1['units_sold']

df2 = df1.groupby('date', as_index=False)['revenue'].sum()
```

Comment: Is it less memory consumpting than `merge`?

Comment: @Aryerez - I think yes

Comment: I hope the OP would comment if it did the job. I may use it one day myself.

Comment: How does this work for multiple columns as mapping objective? Say df1['id2'] = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'] and df2 would have two additional rows for each combination of skew_id and id2? Or should I post that as a separate question? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744786/pandas-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-map) came close

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with a groupby:

```
df.groupby('date').apply(lambda gr: df2.loc[df2.skew_id.isin(list(gr.skew_id))]['skew_price'].sum())
```

Or if you run into memory problems you could loop over all dates yourself. This is slower, but might need less memory.

```
revenue = []
for d in df.date.unique():
    r = df2.loc[df2.skew_id.isin(list(df.loc[df.date == d].skew_id))]['skew_price'].sum()
    revenue.append({'date': d, 'revenue': r})
pd.DataFrame(revenue)
```