# Pandas - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in an dataframe, by creating a dictionary based on an existing column and calling the 'map' function on the column. It seemed to be working for quite some time. However, the notebook started throwing

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

I haven't changed the kernel or the python version. Here's the code i am using.

```
dict= {1:A,
       2:B,
       3:C,
       4:D,
       5:E}

# Creating an interval-type 
data['new'] = data['old'].map(dict)
```

how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535447/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-map)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main problem is after selecting `old` column get `DataFrame` instead `Series`, so `map` implemented yet to `Series` failed.

Here should be duplicated column `old`, so if select one column it return all columns `old` in `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,8],[4,5,3]], columns=['old','old','col'])
print (df)
   old  old  col
0    1    3    8
1    4    5    3

print(df['old'])
   old  old
0    1    3
1    4    5

#dont use dict like variable, because python reserved word
df['new'] = df['old'].map(d)
print (df)
```

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Possible solution for deduplicated this columns:

```
s = df.columns.to_series()
new = s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str).radd('_').replace('_0','')
df.columns += new
print (df)
   old  old_1  col
0    1      3    8
1    4      5    3
```

Another problem should be `MultiIndex` in column, test it by:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['old','old','col'],['a','b','c']])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,8],[4,5,3]], columns=mux)
print (df)
  old    col
    a  b   c
0   1  3   8
1   4  5   3

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['col', 'old'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
           codes=[[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2]])
```

And solution is flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
#python 3.6+
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
#puthon bellow
#df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(a,b) for a, b in df.columns]
print (df)
   old_a  old_b  col_c
0      1      3      8
1      4      5      3
```

Another solution is map by `MultiIndex` with tuple and assign to new `tuple`:

```
df[('new', 'd')] = df[('old', 'a')].map(d)
print (df)
  old    col new
    a  b   c   d
0   1  3   8   A
1   4  5   3   D

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['col', 'old', 'new'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']],
           codes=[[1, 1, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! The problem was indeed because of the duplicate columns. I would never have doubted that. So i was calling pd.concat to call get_dummies on 4 different columns. I was doing this in 4 different pd.concat calls. However, i changed it to make it a single pd.concat call and passed the dataframe and columns attributes to get_dummies. For some reason, this change started creating duplicate columns and i had to revert this change.

Answer (score 9):

map is a method that you can  call on a pandas.Series object. This method doesn't exist on  pandas.DataFrame objects.

```
df['new'] = df['old'].map(d)
```

In your code ^^^ **df['old']** is returning a pandas.Dataframe object for  some reason.

- As @jezrael points out this could be due to having more than one **old** column in the dataframe.
- Or perhaps your code isn't quite the same as the example you have given.
- Either way the error is there because you are calling  **map()** on a pandas.Dataframe object

Comment: @jezrael why would it be keyerror if his code was different?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
f_dict = {1:0,2:1,3:2}
m = pd.Series([1,2,3])
res = m.map(f_dict)
print(res)
```

It's ok because m is pd.Series object. The following usage is wrong because m is pd.DataFrame object.

```
import pandas as pd
f_dict = {1:0,2:1,3:2}
m = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
res = m.map(f_dict)
print(res)
```