# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python, dataset, pandas

I have the following command below:

```
datamax['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamax['Date'])
datamax2015['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamax2015['Date'])
datamax["day_of_year"] = datamax["Date"].dt.dayofyear
datamax2015["day_of_year"] = datamax["Date"].dt.dayofyear
datamaxappend = datamax2015.join(datamax,on="day_of_year",rsuffix="_new")
upper = datamaxappend.loc[datamaxappend["Data_Value_new"]<datamaxappend["Data_Value"]]

upper = upper.rename(columns={"Date_new":"Date","Data_Value_new":"Data_Value"})
lower = lower.rename(columns={"Date_new":"Date","Data_Value_new":"Data_Value"})
upper['Date'] = upper['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
lower['Date'] = lower['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
```

However, I keep getting the error:

**'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'**

I am confused as to why this is. Could anybody help me out here?

The dataframe lower looks like this:

upper:

```
     Date           ID Element  Data_Value  day_of_year       Date  \
3  2015-01-04  USW00094889    TMAX          44            4 2005-01-05   
4  2015-01-05  USW00094889    TMAX          28            5 2005-01-06   
5  2015-01-06  USW00094889    TMAX          33            6 2005-01-07   
14 2015-01-15  USW00094889    TMAX          -5           15 2005-01-16   
15 2015-01-16  USW00094889    TMAX           6           16 2005-01-17   

         ID_new Element_new  Data_Value  day_of_year_new  
3   USW00094889        TMAX          33                5  
4   USW00094889        TMAX           0                6  
5   USW00094889        TMAX           6                7  
14  USW00094889        TMAX         -33               16  
15  USW00094889        TMAX         -50               17
```

lower:

```
   Date           ID Element  Data_Value  day_of_year       Date  \
0 2015-01-01  USC00200032    TMIN        -133            1 2005-01-02   
1 2015-01-02  USC00200032    TMIN        -122            2 2005-01-03   
2 2015-01-03  USC00200032    TMIN         -67            3 2005-01-04   
4 2015-01-05  USC00200032    TMIN        -155            5 2005-01-06   
5 2015-01-06  USC00200032    TMIN        -182            6 2005-01-07   

        ID_new Element_new  Data_Value  day_of_year_new  
0  USC00200032        TMIN         -56                2  
1  USC00200032        TMIN           0                3  
2  USC00200032        TMIN         -39                4  
4  USC00200032        TMIN        -106                6  
5  USC00200032        TMIN        -111                7
```

datamax:

```
     Date           ID Element  Data_Value  day_of_year
    0 2005-01-01  USW00094889    TMAX         156            1
    1 2005-01-02  USW00094889    TMAX         139            2
    2 2005-01-03  USW00094889    TMAX         133            3
    3 2005-01-04  USW00094889    TMAX          39            4
    4 2005-01-05  USW00094889    TMAX          33            5
```

datamin:

```
 Date           ID Element  Data_Value  day_of_year
0 2005-01-01  USC00200032    TMIN         -56            1
1 2005-01-02  USC00200032    TMIN         -56            2
2 2005-01-03  USC00200032    TMIN           0            3
3 2005-01-04  USC00200032    TMIN         -39            4
4 2005-01-05  USC00200032    TMIN         -94            5
```

The dataframe data:

```
                 ID        Date Element  Data_Value
0       USW00094889  2014-11-12    TMAX          22
1       USC00208972  2009-04-29    TMIN          56
2       USC00200032  2008-05-26    TMAX         278
3       USC00205563  2005-11-11    TMAX         139
4       USC00200230  2014-02-27    TMAX        -106
5       USW00014833  2010-10-01    TMAX         194
6       USC00207308  2010-06-29    TMIN         144
7       USC00203712  2005-10-04    TMAX         289
8       USW00004848  2007-12-14    TMIN         -16
9       USC00200220  2011-04-21    TMAX          72
10      USC00205822  2013-01-16    TMAX          11
11      USC00205822  2008-05-29    TMIN          28
12      USC00203712  2008-10-17    TMIN          17
13      USC00205563  2006-05-14    TMAX         183
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upper` and `lower` dataframes have two columns called `Date`. You are extracting both by using `upper['Date']`.

Solution:
Rename at least one of the columns to sth different than date and than apply your function to each column seperately.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54608016/6646710 for further details.

Comment: I've tried what you said and now I get the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '31/12/2005, 00:00:00'

Comment: this is for the line: plt.scatter(upper['Date'],upper['Data_Value'],color='red')

Comment: this line is not part of your code above. If my answer solved your problem above, please consider accepting and or upvoting. For your problem you need to convert your date which is a string into a number as stated by the error message.

Comment: or try `to_datetime` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: ok, yes that's no longer my error: TypeError: invalid type promotion this is my current error, watch this space for new post

Comment: actually I've reached my question limit, so please answer on here or private chat! Would be so grateful, this is very fustrating to have worked so hard and not got anywhere

Comment: I would try sth like `upper['Date'] = upper['Date'].to_datetime(format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='ignore')` & remove 
`upper['Date'] = upper['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))`

Comment: that gave me the error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Comment: actually dw, I've got past that bit, but when I then convert back into datetime, there is a problem with plotting,

Answer (score 0):

1. Python code which returns a line graph of the record high and record low temperatures by day of the year over the period 2005-2014. The area between the record high and record low temperatures for each day should be shaded.
2. Then, overlay a scatter of the 2015 data for any points (highs and lows) for which the ten year record (2005-2014) record high or record low was broken in 2015.
3. Remove leap year dates (i.e. 29th February).

   ```
   from datetime import datetime
   import pandas as pd
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   pd.set_option("display.max_rows",None,"display.max_columns",None)
   data = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv') 
   newdata = data[(data['Date'] >= '2005-01-01') & (data['Date'] <= '2014-12-12')]
   datamax = newdata[newdata['Element']=='TMAX']
   datamin = newdata[newdata['Element']=='TMIN']
   datamax['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamax['Date'])
   datamin['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamin['Date'])
   datamax["day_of_year"] = datamax["Date"].dt.dayofyear
   datamax = datamax.groupby('day_of_year').max()
   datamin["day_of_year"] = datamin["Date"].dt.dayofyear
   datamin = datamin.groupby('day_of_year').min()
   datamax = datamax.reset_index()
   datamin = datamin.reset_index()
   datamin['Date'] = datamin['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   datamax['Date'] = datamax['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   datamax = datamax[~datamax['Date'].str.contains("02-29")]
   datamin = datamin[~datamin['Date'].str.contains("02-29")]

   breakoutdata = data[(data['Date']  > '2014-12-31')]
   datamax2015 = breakoutdata[breakoutdata['Element']=='TMAX']
   datamin2015 = breakoutdata[breakoutdata['Element']=='TMIN']
   datamax2015['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamax2015['Date'])
   datamin2015['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamin2015['Date'])
   datamax2015["day_of_year"] = datamax2015["Date"].dt.dayofyear
   datamax2015 = datamax2015.groupby('day_of_year').max()
   datamin2015["day_of_year"] = datamin2015["Date"].dt.dayofyear
   datamin2015 = datamin2015.groupby('day_of_year').min()
   datamax2015 = datamax2015.reset_index()
   datamin2015 = datamin2015.reset_index()
   datamin2015['Date'] = datamin2015['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   datamax2015['Date'] = datamax2015['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   datamax2015 = datamax2015[~datamax2015['Date'].str.contains("02-29")]
   datamin2015 = datamin2015[~datamin2015['Date'].str.contains("02-29")]

   dataminappend = datamin2015.join(datamin,on="day_of_year",rsuffix="_new")
   lower = dataminappend.loc[dataminappend["Data_Value_new"]>dataminappend["Data_Value"]]
   datamaxappend = datamax2015.join(datamax,on="day_of_year",rsuffix="_new")
   upper = datamaxappend.loc[datamaxappend["Data_Value_new"]<datamaxappend["Data_Value"]]

   upper['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(upper['Date']) 
   lower['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(lower['Date']) 
   datamax['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamax['Date']) 
   datamin['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datamin['Date']) 

   ax = plt.gca()
   plt.plot(datamax['day_of_year'],datamax['Data_Value'],color='red')
   plt.plot(datamin['day_of_year'],datamin['Data_Value'], color='blue')
   plt.scatter(upper['day_of_year'],upper['Data_Value'],color='purple')
   plt.scatter(lower['day_of_year'],lower['Data_Value'], color='cyan')

   plt.ylabel("Temperature (degrees C)",color='navy')
   plt.xlabel("Day of the year",color='navy',labelpad=15)
   plt.title('Record high and low temperatures by day between 2005-2014)', alpha=1.0,color='brown',y=1.08)
   ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.35),fancybox=False,labels=['Record high','Record low'])
   plt.xticks(rotation=30)
   plt.fill_between(range(len(datamax['Date'])), datamax['Data_Value'], datamin['Data_Value'],color='yellow',alpha=0.8)
   plt.show()
   ```
4. I have converted the 'Date' column to a string using Datamin['Date'] = datamin['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').
5. I have then converted this back to 'datetime' format using upper['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(upper['Date'])
6. I then used 'date of year' as the x-value.

[image]