# How to speed up this task in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a large Pandas dataframe, 24'000'000 rows × 6 columns plus index.
I need to read an integer in column 1 (which is = 1 or 2), then force the value in column 3 to be negative if column 1 = 1, or positive if = 2. I use the following code in Jupyter notebook:

```
for i in range(1000):
    if df.iloc[i,1] == 1:
        df.iloc[i,3] = abs(df.iloc[i,3])*(-1)
    if df.iloc[i,1] == 2:
        df.iloc[i,3] = abs(df.iloc[i,3])
```

The code above takes 2min 30sec to run for 1'000 rows only. For the 24M rows, it would take 41 days to complete !

Something is not right. The code runs in Jupyter Notebook/Chrome/Windows on a pretty high end PC.

The Pandas dataframe is created with pd.read_csv and then sorted and indexed this way:

```
df.sort_values(by = "My_time_stamp", ascending=True,inplace = True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

The creation and sorting of the dataframe just takes a few seconds. I have other calculations to perform on this dataframe, so I clearly need to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You are doing exactly what many pandanistas would suggest you not do.  Don't use for loops to do math.

Comment: Read the Pandas docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `np.where`

```
a = np.where(df.iloc[:, 1].to_numpy() == 1, -1, 1)
b = np.abs(df.iloc[:, 3].to_numpy())
df.iloc[:, 3] = a * b
```

Comment: When I try this with a DataFrame, I get the error `'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'`. Would you be willing to show your code with a data example?

Comment: you are using an older version of pandas.  Instead user `df.iloc[:, 1].values` and `df.iloc[:, 3].values`

Comment: Also had the time to test this proposal, it works and is actually the fastest, runs in around 0.51 seconds.Thanks /  Edit: it is the fastest but df.iloc[:, 3] always comes out negative. Something's not right.

Comment: ok, i found the problem, your condition in your where function always return True, so -1.  I changed to : a = np.where(df.iloc[:, 1].to_numpy()==1, -1, 1)   and it works, and is the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Vectorize it:

```
df.iloc[:, 3] = df.iloc[:, 3].abs() * (2 * (df.iloc[:, 1] != 1) - 1)
```

Explanation:

Treated as int, boolean series `df.iloc[:, 1] != 1` gets converted to ones and zeroes. Multiplied by 2, it gets twos and zeroes. After subtracting one, it gets -1 where the first column is 1, and 1 otherwise. Finally, it is multiplied by the absolute value of the third column, which enforces the sign.

Vectorization typically provides an order of magnitude or two speedup comparing to for loops.

Comment: It actually runs slower. 1 min for 100 records, so I assume 10 min for 1'000. So to be sure, I have replaced my 2 IF blocks (4 lines above) with your single line.

Comment: @Hugues no need to loop for with this method, your 5 lines of code can be replaced

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I see it now, indeed, with Marat's line alone it went through the whole 24M rows in about a second ! Talk about improvement, I love my PC again. I need to research vectorization to better understand it as I will really need it for the rest.

Comment: This proposal works and is the second fastest at 0.57 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
df.iloc[:,3] = df.iloc[:,3].abs().mul( df.iloc[:,-1].map({2:1,1:-1}) )
```

Comment: returns: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map' WHich I have researched a bit and found this but not that clear to me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535447/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-map

Comment: I like it, `.map()` doesn't get enough love.

Comment: ok, i had time to test this proposal tonight, the line above works if you correct the typo, it's df.iloc[:,1], not df.iloc[:,-1]. It runs in about 0.88 second for 24M rows, whereas Marat's proposal runs faster in around 0.58 second. Does not make a bit difference for now, but my dataframe is growing at a rate of 1M rows per day. But the .map instruction is easier to grasp for my bird brain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Take an example data set:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,2,1,2], 'x2':[4,8,1,2]})
```

Make new column, code values as -1 and +1:

```
df['nx1'] = df['x1'].replace({1:-1, 2:1})
```

Multiply columnwise:

```
df['nx1'] * df['x2']
```