# How to auto adjust the column width of a excel sheet using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, xlsxwriter

I am trying to auto-adjust the column cells to the excel data i used this code which i found in stack overflow

```
df=pd.read_excel(r"location of the file")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Aparna\Downloads\columnwidth1.xlsx') 
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='my_analysis', index=False, na_rep='NaN')

# Auto-adjust columns' width
for column in df:
    column_width = max(df[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
    col_idx = df.columns.get_loc(column)
    writer.sheets['my_analysis'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)

writer.save()
```

i used this code for increasing the column width but it throws attribute error
`Attribute Error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'`
and the saved excel sheet is not able to open getting file extention is not valid how to over come this here I am sharing the raw data along with expected output https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_iemqwkTYdUCoXKj3O8JNnq3V1ePY5sSRuFD9zDJRPA/edit?usp=sharing this is the link for data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535447/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-map this might be helpful for your case.

Comment: but iam using python and xlsx writer i dont have idea on pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will format column width.

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"location of the file")

with pd.ExcelWriter(r"C:\Users\Aparna\Downloads\columnwidth1.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, startrow=0, sheet_name="my_analysis", index=False)

    for col in pd.Series(range(len(df.columns))).tolist():
        header_name = df.columns[col]
        header_len = len(header_name)
        column_len = df[header_name].map(len).max()
        total_len = sum([header_len, 2]) if header_len > column_len else sum([column_len, 2])

        writer.sheets["my_analysis"].set_column(col, col, total_len)
```

Comment: for this code i am unable to find the excel file not getting any output

Comment: how are you calling it? Also I assume you are on windows double check the path.

Comment: yes windows only but not able to find the file double checked

Comment: did you call the function and pass your df as an argument??

Comment: no, i stored my data in df

Comment: try edit, I removed the function and reformatted the file path to remove those possible sticking points

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() getting this error sir can you use the data which i shared the google drive link above

Comment: Your original data needs cleaned up first such as blank column names